# Trying to perform a recursive query in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I'm trying to perform a query of a bracket, such as an 8, 16, 32, 64 team single elimination bracket.  I would like to know given the starting seeds and games and who has won the previous games, who is playing who.

I have table defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MatchGame] (  
    [MatchGameId]            BIGINT   IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,  
    [MatchSizeId]            BIGINT   NULL,  
    [StartSeedTeamA]         INT      NULL,  
    [StartSeedTeamB]         INT      NULL,  
    [DateEntered]            DATETIME NULL,  
    [DateUpdated]            DATETIME NULL,  
    [MatchNumber]            INT      NULL,  
    [WinnerPlaysMatchNumber] INT      NULL,  
    [RoundNumber]            INT      NULL,  
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MatchGameId] ASC),  
    CONSTRAINT [FK_MatchGame_MatchSize] FOREIGN KEY ([MatchSizeId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[MatchSize] ([MatchSizeId])  
);
```

The MatchSizeId is just a fk to another table with the bracket size and description in it.  It is not really important to the discussion.  The values StartSeedTeamA and StartSeedTeamB have values of 1 to the match size (16, 32, 64, etc.).  The seed values have numbers for the first round, but are null for subsequent rounds.  The matchnumber column has values like 1 for when team 16 plays team 1, 2 for when team 8 plays team 9, etc.  The WinnerPlaysMatchNumber column would have the winner of match 1 playing the winner of match 2 in match 17.  the round number has values that indicate the round of the match.  in a 16 team single elimination event, there are only values 1-4 possible (first round match, 2nd round match, 3rd round match, 4th round match).

What I would like to know is that given a matchsizeid value, I would like to be able to query a matchnumber, and get the allowed values for seed numbers that could be playing in the game.  I know from another table, who won the games.  I was hoping that I could write a sql server cte to do this, but my sql fu is weak.  I have tried something like the following, but to know avail.

```
with matchgames_cte (StartSeedTeamA, StartSeedTeamB, MatchNumber,  
    MatchSizeId, WinnerPlaysMatchNumber, RoundNumber)  
as  
(  
  select StartSeedTeamA, StartSeedTeamB, MatchNumber, MatchSizeId,   
    WinnerPlaysMatchNumber, RoundNumber   
    from MatchGame where RoundNumber = 1  
    UNION ALL  
    select a.StartSeedTeamA, a.StartSeedTeamB, a.MatchNumber, a.MatchSizeId,   
    a.WinnerPlaysMatchNumber, a.roundNumber   
    from MatchGame a INNER JOIN matchgames_cte b on   a.WinnerPlaysMatchNumber=b.matchnumber where a.StartSeedTeamA is null  
)
```

I am attempting to call it with the following query.
    select * from matchgames_cte where matchnumber=13  and matchsizeid=3

Unfortunately, none of my queries against the cte seem to give me any result besides the first round of results.  Any suggestions are appreciated.  thanks for your time.

Wally

Here is some data that was requested:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[MatchGame] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[MatchGame] ([MatchGameId], [MatchSizeId], [StartSeedTeamA], [StartSeedTeamB], [DateEntered], [DateUpdated], [MatchNumber], [WinnerPlaysMatchNumber], [RoundNumber]) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 4, CAST(N'2016-02-11 21:48:27.370' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-02-12 16:03:45.100' AS DateTime), 1, 3, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[MatchGame] ([MatchGameId], [MatchSizeId], [StartSeedTeamA], [StartSeedTeamB], [DateEntered], [DateUpdated], [MatchNumber], [WinnerPlaysMatchNumber], [RoundNumber]) VALUES (2, 1, 2, 3, CAST(N'2016-02-11 21:48:37.863' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-02-12 16:03:46.827' AS DateTime), 2, 3, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[MatchGame] ([MatchGameId], [MatchSizeId], [StartSeedTeamA], [StartSeedTeamB], [DateEntered], [DateUpdated], [MatchNumber], [WinnerPlaysMatchNumber], [RoundNumber]) VALUES (3, 1, NULL, NULL, CAST(N'2016-02-11 21:48:45.917' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-02-12 16:03:53.080' AS DateTime), 3, NULL, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[MatchGame] ([MatchGameId], [MatchSizeId], [StartSeedTeamA], [StartSeedTeamB], [DateEntered], [DateUpdated], [MatchNumber], [WinnerPlaysMatchNumber], [RoundNumber]) VALUES (4, 2, 1, 8, CAST(N'2016-02-11 21:54:40.783' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-02-12 16:03:55.240' AS DateTime), 1, 5, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[MatchGame] ([MatchGameId], [MatchSizeId], [StartSeedTeamA], [StartSeedTeamB], [DateEntered], [DateUpdated], [MatchNumber], [WinnerPlaysMatchNumber], [RoundNumber]) VALUES (5, 2, 5, 4, CAST(N'2016-02-11 21:54:59.317' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-02-12 16:03:56.013' AS DateTime), 2, 5, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[MatchGame] ([MatchGameId], [MatchSizeId], [StartSeedTeamA], [StartSeedTeamB], [DateEntered], [DateUpdated], [MatchNumber], [WinnerPlaysMatchNumber], [RoundNumber]) VALUES (6, 2, 3, 6, CAST(N'2016-02-11 21:55:17.287' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-02-12 16:03:56.930' AS DateTime), 3, 6, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[MatchGame] ([MatchGameId], [MatchSizeId], [StartSeedTeamA], [StartSeedTeamB], [DateEntered], [DateUpdated], [MatchNumber], [WinnerPlaysMatchNumber], [RoundNumber]) VALUES (7, 2, 2, 7, CAST(N'2016-02-11 21:55:45.730' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-02-12 16:03:57.710' AS DateTime), 4, 6, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[MatchGame] ([MatchGameId], [MatchSizeId], [StartSeedTeamA], [StartSeedTeamB], [DateEntered], [DateUpdated], [MatchNumber], [WinnerPlaysMatchNumber], [RoundNumber]) VALUES (8, 2, NULL, NULL, CAST(N'2016-02-11 21:56:12.327' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-02-12 16:03:58.883' AS DateTime), 5, 7, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[MatchGame] ([MatchGameId], [MatchSizeId], [StartSeedTeamA], [StartSeedTeamB], [DateEntered], [DateUpdated], [MatchNumber], [WinnerPlaysMatchNumber], [RoundNumber]) VALUES (9, 2, NULL, NULL, CAST(N'2016-02-11 21:56:30.340' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-02-12 16:03:59.817' AS DateTime), 6, 7, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[MatchGame] ([MatchGameId], [MatchSizeId], [StartSeedTeamA], [StartSeedTeamB], [DateEntered], [DateUpdated], [MatchNumber], [WinnerPlaysMatchNumber], [RoundNumber]) VALUES (10, 2, NULL, NULL, CAST(N'2016-02-11 21:56:43.483' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-02-12 16:04:02.397' AS DateTime), 7, NULL, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[MatchGame] ([MatchGameId], [MatchSizeId], [StartSeedTeamA], [StartSeedTeamB], [DateEntered], [DateUpdated], [MatchNumber], [WinnerPlaysMatchNumber], [RoundNumber]) VALUES (11, 3, 1, 16, CAST(N'2016-02-11 22:12:16.467' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-02-12 16:04:06.040' AS DateTime), 1, 9, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[MatchGame] ([MatchGameId], [MatchSizeId], [StartSeedTeamA], [StartSeedTeamB], [DateEntered], [DateUpdated], [MatchNumber], [WinnerPlaysMatchNumber], [RoundNumber]) VALUES (12, 3, 8, 9, CAST(N'2016-02-11 22:12:32.533' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-02-12 16:04:06.630' AS DateTime), 2, 9, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[MatchGame] ([MatchGameId], [MatchSizeId], [StartSeedTeamA], [StartSeedTeamB], [DateEntered], [DateUpdated], [MatchNumber], [WinnerPlaysMatchNumber], [RoundNumber]) VALUES (13, 3, 4, 13, CAST(N'2016-02-11 22:12:50.027' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-02-12 16:04:07.197' AS DateTime), 3, 10, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[MatchGame] ([MatchGameId], [MatchSizeId], [StartSeedTeamA], [StartSeedTeamB], [DateEntered], [DateUpdated], [MatchNumber], [WinnerPlaysMatchNumber], [RoundNumber]) VALUES (14, 3, 5, 12, CAST(N'2016-02-11 22:13:06.283' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-02-12 16:04:08.087' AS DateTime), 4, 10, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[MatchGame] ([MatchGameId], [MatchSizeId], [StartSeedTeamA], [StartSeedTeamB], [DateEntered], [DateUpdated], [MatchNumber], [WinnerPlaysMatchNumber], [RoundNumber]) VALUES (15, 3, 3, 14, CAST(N'2016-02-11 22:13:30.960' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-02-12 16:04:08.880' AS DateTime), 5, 11, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[MatchGame] ([MatchGameId], [MatchSizeId], [StartSeedTeamA], [StartSeedTeamB], [DateEntered], [DateUpdated], [MatchNumber], [WinnerPlaysMatchNumber], [RoundNumber]) VALUES (16, 3, 6, 11, CAST(N'2016-02-11 22:13:42.627' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-02-12 16:04:09.787' AS DateTime), 6, 11, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[MatchGame] ([MatchGameId], [MatchSizeId], [StartSeedTeamA], [StartSeedTeamB], [DateEntered], [DateUpdated], [MatchNumber], [WinnerPlaysMatchNumber], [RoundNumber]) VALUES (17, 3, 7, 10, CAST(N'2016-02-11 22:14:09.203' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-02-12 16:04:11.563' AS DateTime), 7, 12, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[MatchGame] ([MatchGameId], [MatchSizeId], [StartSeedTeamA], [StartSeedTeamB], [DateEntered], [DateUpdated], [MatchNumber], [WinnerPlaysMatchNumber], [RoundNumber]) VALUES (18, 3, 15, 2, CAST(N'2016-02-11 22:14:22.803' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-02-12 16:04:13.473' AS DateTime), 8, 12, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[MatchGame] ([MatchGameId], [MatchSizeId], [StartSeedTeamA], [StartSeedTeamB], [DateEntered], [DateUpdated], [MatchNumber], [WinnerPlaysMatchNumber], [RoundNumber]) VALUES (19, 3, NULL, NULL, CAST(N'2016-02-11 22:14:41.130' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-02-12 16:04:18.120' AS DateTime), 9, 13, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[MatchGame] ([MatchGameId], [MatchSizeId], [StartSeedTeamA], [StartSeedTeamB], [DateEntered], [DateUpdated], [MatchNumber], [WinnerPlaysMatchNumber], [RoundNumber]) VALUES (20, 3, NULL, NULL, CAST(N'2016-02-11 22:14:48.930' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-02-12 16:04:18.777' AS DateTime), 10, 13, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[MatchGame] ([MatchGameId], [MatchSizeId], [StartSeedTeamA], [StartSeedTeamB], [DateEntered], [DateUpdated], [MatchNumber], [WinnerPlaysMatchNumber], [RoundNumber]) VALUES (21, 3, NULL, NULL, CAST(N'2016-02-11 22:15:01.407' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-02-12 16:04:19.493' AS DateTime), 11, 14, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[MatchGame] ([MatchGameId], [MatchSizeId], [StartSeedTeamA], [StartSeedTeamB], [DateEntered], [DateUpdated], [MatchNumber], [WinnerPlaysMatchNumber], [RoundNumber]) VALUES (22, 3, NULL, NULL, CAST(N'2016-02-11 22:15:13.843' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-02-12 16:04:20.443' AS DateTime), 12, 14, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[MatchGame] ([MatchGameId], [MatchSizeId], [StartSeedTeamA], [StartSeedTeamB], [DateEntered], [DateUpdated], [MatchNumber], [WinnerPlaysMatchNumber], [RoundNumber]) VALUES (23, 3, NULL, NULL, CAST(N'2016-02-11 22:15:23.607' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-02-12 16:04:23.297' AS DateTime), 13, 15, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[MatchGame] ([MatchGameId], [MatchSizeId], [StartSeedTeamA], [StartSeedTeamB], [DateEntered], [DateUpdated], [MatchNumber], [WinnerPlaysMatchNumber], [RoundNumber]) VALUES (24, 3, NULL, NULL, CAST(N'2016-02-11 22:15:31.050' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-02-12 16:04:24.237' AS DateTime), 14, 15, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[MatchGame] ([MatchGameId], [MatchSizeId], [StartSeedTeamA], [StartSeedTeamB], [DateEntered], [DateUpdated], [MatchNumber], [WinnerPlaysMatchNumber], [RoundNumber]) VALUES (25, 3, NULL, NULL, CAST(N'2016-02-11 22:15:36.730' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-02-12 16:04:25.867' AS DateTime), 15, NULL, 4)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[MatchGame] OFF
GO
```

Here is an example query that I am trying to run:

```
with matchgames_cte (StartSeedTeamA, StartSeedTeamB, MatchNumber,
    MatchSizeId, WinnerPlaysMatchNumber, RoundNumber)
as
(
  select StartSeedTeamA, StartSeedTeamB, MatchNumber, MatchSizeId, 
    WinnerPlaysMatchNumber, RoundNumber 
    from MatchGame where WinnerPlaysMatchNumber is null
    UNION ALL
    select a.StartSeedTeamA, a.StartSeedTeamB, a.MatchNumber, a.MatchSizeId, 
    a.WinnerPlaysMatchNumber, a.roundNumber 
    from MatchGame a INNER JOIN matchgames_cte b on     b.MatchNumber=a.WinnerPlaysMatchNumber where Not(a.WinnerPlaysMatchNumber is null)
)
select * from matchgames_cte where StartSeedTeamA is not null and MatchNumber=14
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data? It would also help if you posted the actual query you were trying.

Comment: Have you tried switching the join criteria from `a.WinnerPlaysMatchNumber=b.matchnumber` to `b.WinnerPlaysMatchNumber=a.matchnumber`? I think the `WinnerPlaysMatchNumber` should come from the CTE and join to the Match number on the `MatchRound` table.

Comment: Thanks Sean.  I have added some data, though it looks horrible in the question.  Apologies for that.  Wayne, I have tried that change as well with no luck.

Comment: I kept looking at this and finally came up with what I think is the answer.  I've pasted it below.  it is a sql server function that I wrote on this using a cte.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your recursion is correct but in the final WHERE clause you attempt to:

- filter by `MatchNumber` which looks like supposed to be unique per hierarchy (I don't see only one row for MatchNumber=13 and another for MatchNumber=14)
- filter by `StartSeedTeamA` which is NULL almost everywhere in your sample data

probably this will help to find seed teams for next match:

```
select next.MatchNumber, prior.StartSeedTeamA, prior.StartSeedTeamB, prior.MatchNumber as FinishedMatchNumber
from MatchGame next
inner join MatchGame prior on next.MatchNumber = prior.WinnerPlaysMatchNumber
where next.StartSeedTeamA is NULL and prior.StartSeedTeamA is not NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I kept looking at this and finally came up with what I think is the answer.  I've pasted it below.  it is a sql server function that I wrote on this using a cte.  any suggestions are appreciated regarding improvements.  Thanks for your time.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_StartSeeds]  
(  
    @matchsizeid bigint,  
    @startmatchnumber int  
)  
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN  
(  
    with matchgames_cte (StartSeedTeamA, StartSeedTeamB, MatchNumber, MatchSizeId, winnerplaysmatchnumber)  
    as  
    (  
      select StartSeedTeamA, StartSeedTeamB, MatchNumber, MatchSizeId, WinnerPlaysMatchNumber
        from MatchGame where MatchNumber = @startmatchnumber and MatchSizeId = @matchsizeid  
        UNION ALL  
        select a.StartSeedTeamA, a.StartSeedTeamB, a.MatchNumber, a.MatchSizeId, a.WinnerPlaysMatchNumber
        from MatchGame a JOIN matchgames_cte b on b.MatchNumber=a.WinnerPlaysMatchNumber where a.WinnerPlaysMatchNumber is not null and a.MatchSizeId = @matchsizeid  
    )  
    select * from matchgames_cte where MatchSizeId=@matchsizeid and StartSeedTeamA is not null  
)
```